# Can you run mac os x binary on darwin?

Tags: macos, frameworks, darwin

Are the OS X & Darwin executable/framework/library formats the same? If you compile a command line tool using only say Foundation.framework and you have another system running Darwin(same architecture). If you copy the Foundation.framework from Mac OS X will you be able to run your program in Darwin?

Comment: No idea.  Why don't you try it yourself?  It seems like it would be easier to test it on your own and post an answer here that could benefit others.

Comment: I believe it should work, OS X (has kernel around Darwin), this should work I believe.

Comment: The binary formats are most likely the same, but copying Foundation will not be sufficient to get such a program working. The Foundation framework depends on many other libraries and frameworks. And those, in turn, probably depend on others. You'll probably have to copy a lot. Perhaps easier to boot an OS X install with an alternative kernel.

Comment: @CodaFi To be honest, I'm not exactly sure where to even start. But if I figure it out and try it out I will post an update.

Comment: @RenoJones that's what I assumed too but I was curious if someone with more knowledge would be able to confirm/deny.

Comment: @KenThomases True, I'd probabily end up having to copy around a lot of stuff. I was thinking more along the lines of a minimal darwin based distro that you could run as a server in a vps or something.